# converting XMLHttpRequest to JSONP

Tags: javascript, ajax

help, I need to change this code to support remote domain access:

```
document.write(url);
    var http = getHTTPObject();
      http.open("GET", url, true);
      http.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (http.readyState == 4) {
              parseData(http.responseText);
          }
      }
      http.send(null);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your js:

```
function goRemote(url) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src=url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
function parseDate(json) {
  // do your fun here.
}
```

in your returned js:

```
parseData({"foo": "bar"});
```

Comment: Actually, HEAD tag can not have "id" attribute in HTML4.01. Instead making your markup invalid and accessing HEAD element by ID, use `getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` (or any kind of selector utility available, such as `$` in jQuery, `$$` in Prototype.js, etc.)

Comment: Don't bother messing around with the head, just document.body.appendChild